# Two boards sharing same slider (jsxGraph), posible?

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

Like titles states I need two boards sharing the same slider. Lets say

```
var s = board3.create('slider',[[-10,-5],[-5,-5],[-11,-11,5]]);
```

and then another board (board4) to have the same slider meaning it reacts on on the slide of slider s
Is this possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Two boards can be connected with the command "board.addChild()". In your case, there are the two boards "board3" and "board4". Whenever board3 is updated, board4 should also receive a board update event call. This can be achieved by the call of "board3.addChild(board4)":

```
var board3 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox3', {axis:true, boundingbox: [-15,10,15,-10], keepaspectratio:false}),
    board4 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox4', {axis:true, boundingbox: [-15,10,15,-10], keepaspectratio:false});

board3.addChild(board4);

// slider s in board3 and 
// point p in board4 which reacts to slider s
var s = board3.create('slider', [[-10,-5],[-5,-5],[-11,-11,5]]),
    p = board4.create('point', [function() {
                return s.Value();
            },
            function() {
                return 0.5 * s.Value();
            }]);
```